# Restrict access to file/folder in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I've tried all manner of variations in trying to restrict access to a folder, from the simplest of denying access to all users and just granting access to myself to trying a combination of roles/users etc.  In particular, the folder has a mix of aspx and html files.

Can anyone assist?  Here's pretty much what I have based on other similar questions:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
       <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="HTMLHandler" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
    <location path="AdminOnly">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
            <deny users="*" />
            <allow users="domain\user1, domain\user2, domain\user3" />
            <allow roles="domain\role1, domain\role2" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**
The solution has presented at last.

It was a combination of understanding the authorization segment (thanks to Tetsuya for the helpful tip in relation to ordering authorization rules), including the handler segment and also configuring the application pool for managed code.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Seems you have wrong order in composing `authorization` element, the `allow` part must be declared first to allow certain users in certain roles before denying everything else.

So, this construction below is wrong due to denying all users resolved before allowing defined users:

```
<location path="AdminOnly">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
        <allow users="domain\user1, domain\user2, domain\user3" />
        <allow roles="domain\role1, domain\role2" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The correct order should be like this:

```
<location path="AdminOnly">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
        <allow roles="role1, role2" />
        <allow users="user1, user2, user3" />
        <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

In the reference section, Guru Sarkar explains what goes wrong:

> **Common Mistakes**
>
> I have seen people complaining that they have setup their roles
>   correctly and also made entry to their web.config but still their
>   authorization doesn't work. Even they have allowed access to their
>   role that user cannot access particular page/folder. The common reason
>   for that is placing `<deny../>` before `<allow ../>`. Since the *authorization is done from top to bottom*, rules are checked until a match is found.

Reference:

[Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config)

Comment: the issue seems to be more around blocking access to html files within the directory.  As soon as I include the handler, access to the html file is denied irrespective of what I put in the authorization section.

Comment: Changed the application pool to use .Net version 4 from no managed code and it's now working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to create new web.config in your specific folder and add this into your folder's web.config to restrict all users

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks hasan, yes, I did actually work up from there, so that works

Comment: it works, but it isn't the solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

We accomplished this with a URL rewrite.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="RestrictAccess" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="MyFolder/MyFile.zip" />
                <action type="AbortRequest" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```